# How is a plugin swappable?

Tags: 8, plugins

Hi I am newbe in Drupal 8 and learning the new plugin system introduced in Drupal 8. I understood the concept of pluggin and also created few plugins like block and field fomatters. But I am not able to undestand the defination of pluging. Like it says

> "A plugin is a small piece of functionality that may be swapped in and
>   out of your drupal site"

Can someone please explain (with example) the term swapped is used in context of Drupal 8.

Comment: Sorry, but this question is way too broad. We answer narrow questions asking for solutions to specific problems you weren't able to fix yourself after trying. You also don't name your source which we'd need to get the context of your question.

Comment: @leymannx Sorry for asking broad question here in the community. I am very confused about the term used swapple for pluggin. I cound'nt find a proper example where I cud undestand the swapple concept in plugin. The defination is mentioned in "Enterpise drupal 8 development by Todd Tomlinson.

Comment: @4k4 If plugin is swapable? Swaping of plugin talks about what feature plugin system in drupal 8?

Comment: All plugins are swappable on plugin manager level, see the duplicate. Also each plugin type is plugable in specific ways, for example blocks in block layout, field formatters in content types or menu links in yaml files. If you have a question about one of those ask a more specific quesiton.